Relation about line picking on $n$-sphere and $n$-ball
Define $ S[n] $ as the expected distance between two points uniformly distributed on the surface of a $n$-sphere of radius $1$ (here you can find the explicit values). Now define $ B[n] $ as the expected distance between two points uniformly distributed within the $n$-ball of radius $1$ (here the explicit values).
It is easy to note that $ S[n+2] = \frac{n-1}{n-2} B[n]$. Is there any reason for this simple result?

How is it easy to note "$S[n+2] = \frac{n-1}{n-2} B[n]$"?

@mathworker21well I just confronted the values

Intuitively, the reason for this is that a uniform distribution on $S^{n+1}$ will give a uniform distribution on $B^n$ under the projection $S^{n+1}\rightarrow B^n$, and the average scaling factor of distances under this projection is the same as the average distance from the origin in $B^n$ as a result. Details are given as follows.
Let $S^{n+1}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ be the standard unit $(n+1)$-sphere and $B^n\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ be the unit $n$-ball in $\mathbb{R}^n\times\{(0,0)\}$. Let $p:S^{n+1}\rightarrow B^n$ be the projection that zeroes its last two coordinates, i.e.,$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2})\mapsto(x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,0).$$
Claim 1: If $X$ uniformly distributed on $S^{n+1}$, then $p(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $B^n$.
To show that $p(X)$ is uniform, we want show that the probability that $p(X)$ falls within a small neighborhood $N$ (w.r.t. the subset topology on $B^n$) of the point $x$ depends only on the $n$-volume of $N$, not $x$. Since $X$ is uniformly distributed, this amounts to showing that the $(n+1)$-volume of $p^{-1}(N)$ is a constant multiple of the $n$-volume of $N$.
The diagram below works in all dimensions, but try to visualize in the $n=1$ case first. Let $x\in B^n$. Consider $p$ on the slice of $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$ with the $(n+1)$st coordinate positive and the $(n+2)$nd coordinate $0$. In this slice, $p$ maps the point $y=(x_1,\ldots,x_n,r,0)\in S^{n+1}$ to the point $x$. To the first approximation, the restriction of $p$ scales $n$-volumes by $\sin\theta=r$ near $y$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $y$ and $x$. Thus, within this slice, the preimage of a small neighborhood of $n$-volume $V$ will have $n$-volume $V/r$.
The full set of points that map to $x$ is given by rotating $y$ around $x$ to get a circle of radius $r$: $(x_1,\ldots,x_n,r\cos\phi,r\sin\phi)$. Consequently, we can just take the "surface" of revolution of what we found in the slice, meaning the preimage of a small neighborhood of $n$-volume $V$ will have $(n+1)$-volume $2\pi r(V/r)=2\pi V$ (to the first approximation). Since this is a constant multiple of $V$ irrespective of our choice of $x$, we have proven the claim.

Claim 2: The distance between two points chosen uniformly at random on $S^{n+1}$ will scale by an expected value of $\frac{n}{n+1}$ under projection onto $B^n$.
Note that how the distance scales under projection does not actually depend on the distance between our two points, just the direction of the line segment between them. Taking this direction as a unit vector $u$ from the first point to the second, we see that the scaling factor is $|p(u)|$. This direction as also necessarily uniformly distributed on $S^{n+1}$, so it suffices to find the expected value of $|p|$ on $S^{n+1}$. By claim 1, this is equivalent to finding the average value of $|x|$ for $x\in B^n$.
To calculate this average value, we note that the value $|x|=r$ will be weighted by the $(n-1)$-volume of the $(n-1)$-sphere with radius $r$. Since $$\text{Vol}_{n-1}(S^{n-1}(r))=\frac{d}{dr}\text{Vol}_n(B_n(r))=\frac{n}{r}\text{Vol}_n(B_n(r))=nr^{n-1}\text{Vol}_n(B_n(1)),$$ we have $$\frac{\int_0^1r\text{Vol}_{n-1}(S^{n-1}(r))dr}{\text{Vol}_n(B_n(1))}=\frac{\int_0^1nr^n{\text{Vol}_n(B_n(1))}dr}{\text{Vol}_n(B_n(1))}=\int_0^1nr^ndr=\frac{n}{n+1}$$ as the expected scaling factor.
By claims 1 and 2, we find the the average distance between two points on $S^{n+1}$ is $\frac{n+1}{n}$ times the average distance between two points on $B^n$.
